# Ambiguous use of operator '-' with two Uint's

Tags: swift, swift2

In XCode beta 5, when I execute the following code in the playground:

```
import Swift

let a = UInt(0)
let b = UInt(0)
var string = ""

string += a + b > 1 ?
    "true" :
    "false"

let bool = a - b > 1
string += bool ?
    "true" :
    "false"

string = a - b > 1 ?
    "true" :
    "false"

string += a - b > 1 ? //ERROR
    "true" :
    "false"
```

I get the following error:

```
Playground execution failed: /var/folders/ws/cpskvst94cq5fb0vjmljzmkw0000gn/T/./lldb/41335/playground29.swift:10:13: error: ambiguous use of operator '-'
string += a - b > 1 ?
            ^
Swift.-:1:6: note: found this candidate
func -<T : Strideable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T.Stride
     ^
Swift.-:1:6: note: found this candidate
func -<T : _DisallowMixedSignArithmetic>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T._DisallowMixedSignArithmetic
```

Is this intended? Why does only the last line produce an error?

Comment: Even `string = string + (a - b > 1 ? "true" : "false")` produces the same error.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the full answer, but perhaps what I have found will help someone figure out the rest of it:

`a - b` can be interpreted as either of these:

```
func -(lhs: UInt, rhs: UInt) -> UInt
func -<T : Strideable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> T.Stride
```

So the result is either `UInt` or `UInt.Stride`.  The literal `1` can be interpreted as either because this works:

```
let f: UInt.Stride = 1
```

For some unknown reason, the `+=` is making Swift interpret `a - b` as `UInt.Stride` instead of `UInt`.  Note that the following yields the same error:

```
let e: UInt.Stride = a - b
```

If you use `UInt(1)` instead of `1`, it works:

```
string += a - b > UInt(1) ? "true" : "false"
```

I believe this works because it forces Swift to see `a - b` as yielding a `UInt`, because it only has a `>` that takes two `UInt` (and not `UInt.Stride` and `UInt`).  Note if you force `1` to be `UInt.Stride`:

```
let f: UInt.Stride = 1
```

this yields the same error:

```
string += a - b > f ? "true" : "false"
```

Another workaround is to use `UInt()` around `a - b`:

```
string += UInt(a - b) > 1 ? "true" : "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not intended since there is a dedicated `-` operator for `UInt`.

```
func -(lhs: UInt, rhs: UInt) -> UInt
```

There is also no reason why only the last line produces this error.

As workaround you can make a new variable:

```
let aMinusb = a - b
string += aMinusb > 1 ? "true" : "false"
```

Side note: In Swift 1.2 the error is the same.

Comment: Another workaround `string += a - b > UInt(1) ? "true" : "false"`